# Solving an equation with a shift

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

My professor offered an extra exercise for us to think about.

The problem is to solve the shifted equation of the form
$$
f(x+ia) = x^2 f(x) \, ,
$$
where $a$ is a constant.

Due to the $x$-dependent factor, the exponential ansatz is not applicable here.

Currently, I have no idea on how to proceed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x$ is a real number and that $0$ and $1$ are allowed values of $i$, then this equation has only $f(x)=0$ as a solution.  This can be shown as follows.

When $i=0$ we have $f(x)=x^2f(x)$ for $x\neq\pm1$. Only $f(x)=0$ satisfies this equation, thus $f(x)=0$ for all $x\neq\pm1$

When $i=1$ we have $f(x+a)=x^2f(x)$ Substituting $x=1$ we get $f(1+a)=f(1)$.  If $a\neq-2$ then the left hand side is $0$ since $f(x)$ is $0$ for all $x\neq\pm1$ and thus $f(1)=0$.  If $a=-2$ we can simply apply the shift again to get $f(1)=f(-1)=f(-3)=0$.  A similar argument can be made by substituting $x=-1$ to show $f(-1)=0$.

Putting this together shows that for all $x$ we have $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, the symbol $i$ denotes the imaginary number.